# How to include redefined methods in a class with include

Tags: ruby

I wrote this module:

```
module Hooks
  module ExecutionHooks
    def before_action(hook, *method_names)
      method_names.each do |method_name|
        method = method(method_name)
        define_singleton_method(method_name) do |*args, &block|
          method(hook).call(*args)
          method.call(*args, &block)
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def self.included(base)
    base.send(:extend, Hooks::ExecutionHooks)
  end
end
```

This module allows other modules or classes to define a hook which should be called before a particular action similar to a `before_action` in Rails.
Then I included this module in my HTTParty module:

```
module HTTParty
  include Hooks
  before_action :perform_action, :get

  def self.perform_action
    puts "performed"
  end
end
```

There is a class which includes the HTTParty module:

```
class TestClient 
  include HTTParty
  ...
end
```

When I try to access the `get` method in TestClient, it doesn't call `perform_action`. The `get` method being included here is original one, not the redefined one.

Is there a way to include the redefined `get` method in the TestClient class?

Comment: I think your code looks very close to goal, but a more modern way is to use `super` with `Module#prepend`.

Comment: I am pretty new to Ruby. Please explain, at what point in code should I be using Module#prepend?

Comment: Please read the `prepend` documentation, research further if necessary and experiment before asking for us to write more documentation.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention ruby version which I am using. It is 2.0.0p247. 
I did some research on `Module#prepend`. I am not completely clear about it yet but looks like this is what I need. The problem is that `prepend` is private in this version of ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code almost works, but `get` isn't actually defined directly on `HTTParty`, which you didn't expect, and `HTTParty`'s `included` class method adds `get` to your class through another path.

`HTTParty` has a module called `HTTParty::ClassMethods` that contains `get`, etc. It puts them in two places: on `HTTParty` itself so you can call `HTTParty.get`, and on any class with `include HTTParty`, via the `included` hook. When you open up `module HTTParty` and `include Hooks`, you're inserting hooks on `HTTParty.get`, which is a different lookup chain that when you call `TestClient.get`. Leaving your `Hooks::ExecutionHooks` module alone, I recommend making a `HookedHTTParty` module instead of monkeypatching `HTTParty`. That will make it more clear what's going on and avoid the complexity of `HTTParty`'s internals, which we shouldn't really be fiddling with.

```
# hooked_httparty.rb
require 'httparty'
require 'hooks'

module HookedHTTParty
  module ClassMethods
    def global_perform(*args)
      puts "Running global perform with args #{args.inspect}"
    end
  end

  def self.included(base)
    base.include(HTTParty)
    base.include(Hooks)
    base.extend(HookedHTTParty::ClassMethods)
    base.before_action :global_perform, :get
  end
end
```

This makes sure `HTTParty` and `Hooks` are available on `base`, and then extends it with the `global_perform` hook on every `get`. The primary different from your initial code is that `before_action` gets called on `base` (`TestClient`) instead of on `HTTParty`, so we catch the right `get` method. You'll also notice `global_perform` accepts `*args`, since you're calling it that way when you generate the hook.

Because we include `Hooks`, you now also have access to `before_action` in `TestClient` itself, so you can also define more specific `before_action`s:

```
class TestClient
  include HookedHTTParty

  before_action :local_perform, :get

  def self.local_perform(*args)
    puts "Running local perform with args #{args.inspect}"
  end
end
```

Running `get` looks like this:

```
> TestClient.get 'https://www.stackoverflow.com'
Running local perform with args ["https://www.stackoverflow.com"]
Running global perform with args ["https://www.stackoverflow.com"]
 => #<HTTParty::Response:0x7fa523a009e0 ... >
```

If you really need anything including `HTTParty` to get your hooks (perhaps because you don't have control of the thing including it), you might need to monkeypatch `HTTParty::ClassMethods` directly, since that's the bottleneck where `get` is defined, but that's getting into even darker territory. As long as you're injecting code around, you could also `OtherThing.include(HookedHTTParty)` to make it more explicit and keep it just a bit more encapsulated.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying all the doubts. I am migrating from Java to Ruby so it is taking some time to understand the difference in behaviour of both the languages.